# How to remove the first blank cell from sort formula when sort in decending order?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a sort formula, `SORT(UNIQUE('Logs'!A2:A),1,FALSE)` to sort column A in 'Logs' sheet in descending order. However, each time it results in a blank cell in its first result. How to remove that?

A sample result, where there are always a blank cell on top:

[Blank]

99

76

43

22

19

16

2

1

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a query in front.

`QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE('Logs'!A2:A),1,FALSE),"")`

You don't have to query for anything, but the query function will exclude the blank cell first, and then find out you didn't tell it to do anything, so it just returns the result after removing the blank cell.